# NSSpellChecker does not display my custom dictionaries from ~/Library/Spelling with Node js

Tags: node.js, objective-c, macos, node-gyp

Node Version: node 12.18.3, npm 6.14.6
Platform: macOS

I try to use **NSSpellChecker** in my **nodejs native module** to list all available system languages but it always returns me only installed system languages.

1. I added a custom dictionary to the folder `~/Library/Spelling`.
2. Created .node module ( with **node-gyp** )
3. start JS script which returns me [available languages](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsspellchecker/1530496-availablelanguages)

Objective C:

```
#import "spellchecker.h"
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <dispatch/dispatch.h>

Spellchecker::Spellchecker() {
    NSLog(@"%@",[[NSSpellChecker sharedSpellChecker] availableLanguages]);
    NSLog(@"%lu",[[[NSSpellChecker sharedSpellChecker] availableLanguages] count]);
}

Spellchecker::~Spellchecker() {}
```

*with nodejs: it displayed only 34 languages*

*with a simple objective c app in Xcode: all 35 languages (include my custom dictionary)*

[image]

Please, any workaround to fix it?